# python cv2 matching descriptors for high spatial frequency images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm using python's opencv version 3.2.0 along with opencv contrib for a small project of detecting LEDs status within a hard drive enclosure.
The disk enclosure is full of disks which look the same, thus the image has high spatial frequency.

For detecting the descriptors I use SIFT algorithm 
and for matching the descriptors of the image with those of a given template I used 2 different functions of cv2, and both failed (namely found bad matches):

FLANN:

```
if obj.descriptors.dtype == 'uint8':
    # ORB creates binary descriptors, so we use LSH indexer
    FLANN_INDEX_TYPE = 6
elif obj.descriptors.dtype == 'float32':
    # SIFT creates float descriptors, so use KD-Tree indexer
    FLANN_INDEX_TYPE = 0


index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_TYPE,
               table_number=6,  # 12
               key_size=12,  # 20
               multi_probe_level=1) # 2

search_params = dict(checks=50)  # or pass empty dictionary

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(obj.descriptors, img.descriptors, k=2)
```

BFMATCHER:

```
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(obj.descriptors, img.descriptors, k=2)
```

and later on using this loop, for eliminating bad matches according to distance:

```
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
        obj_m.append(obj.keypoints[m.queryIdx].pt)
        img_m.append(img.keypoints[m.trainIdx].pt)
```

What do you recommend of doing in order to improve the matches for high spatial frequency objects?

Thanks in advance,
Regev

Comment: Can you post your sample images (input images and templates)?